# How to Read The com.apple.screencapture

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

I need to turn of the screencapture feature from the operating system... I've seen ways to change options like:

```
default write com.apple.screencapture type <format>
```

But I can't find the way to read from it... for instance

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture
// Get the following error: Domain com.apple.screencapture does not exist
```

Any ideas on how to disable the app or at least read the options available?

Comment: It may not have any defaults written, if nothing has been changed. Often those 'keys' only exist once changed.

Comment: any idea how to disable?? I need to prevent users from taking screenshot

Comment: Assuming they are not an admin user & can't simply re-enable it ... System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screen Shots. Uncheck. You might need to enable parental controls to lock them out from using the Grab Utility though.

Comment: It needs to be done from the terminal... because I will run the script on the background of my application

Comment: It cannot be done at application level - there are a lot of similar questions scattered about the 'net, with similarly disappointed coders.. It's a built-in system service. Closest you can get is to remove the key commands. the `defaults read com.apple.screencapture` only covers file type, location & drop shadow afaik.